# Firebase Hosting and Http2

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, http2, firebase-hosting

So I've got an Angular site being hosted on Firebase hosting. Technically, it's a cloud function that serves the site with SSR (not sure if that matters for this question). 
I'm running Chrome's Lighthouse Audit trying to get that sweet perfect score, but the only thing holding me back is the "Does not use HTTP/2 for all of its resources" complaint (my index, js, css, and images are requested with http/1.1).

I thought Firebase was supposed to use http/2 for all its requests by default. Am I missing something here, any configuration I'm supposed to set or something?

Thanks!

Comment: So your page is returned by HTTP/2 but the js, css and images are not? Are they from same domain? What domain is it?

Comment: @BarryPollard no, the site is http/1.1 as well. Editing post for clarity

Comment: You might be running into [this bug](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/7158) in lighthouse.

Comment: @abraham you are correct-- thanks